# How do I re direct STDERR to STDOUT when using system() command in Perl? The 2>&1 solution is not working

Tags: perl, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I'm calling the system function from a subroutine.
the code looks something like this:

```
sub execCmd;
my @cmd_line;
my $cmd_file_name;

#pre-process argv to open a file to read the command.
open(F,'<',"$cmd_file_name);
my $temp=<F>;
chomp($temp);
@cmd_line=split(/ /, "$temp");
close F;
execCmd();

sub execCmd {
    my $test_stat=system("@cmd_line cmd_args 2>&1");
    if($test_stat){
           print "TEST FAILED";
           exit;
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You are mistaken. `system`, when provided a single scalar, expects it to be `sh` command, and the `sh` command you provided does what you requested it does.

Comment: Also, please don't call your subs by the same name as Perl operators (e.g. `exec`).

Comment: What fix do you suggest?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Right now, I'm not able to see the error messages on STDOUT. But when I run the same command from a shell script, I can see the errors on the STDOUT. Need to make this perl script to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your subroutine is never called because it shadows the existing Perl function `exec`. Instead when you call `exec()` it is running the real `exec` and since you've not passed it any parameters, it does nothing.

Since your sub is calling `exit(0)` you might as well ditch your subroutine and call the real `exec` like this which will do the same thing

```
exec("cmd cmd_args 2>&1");
```

Comment: I didn't want to post the exact name of the sub-routine, hence the name 'exec' didn't realize that I was using the same name as a Perl operator. Can't make do with exec since I need the exit code of the command I'm executing.

Comment: But your code doesn't show that you're using the exit code from the command so how do you expect a proper answer if you're not giving us all the information?

Comment: Hi, I edited the code and that's exactly what I'm doing. Could you go through it. Thanks in advance!